# Is there a way to turn off mouse movement or somthing like that while script is running in Logitech Lua?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```lua
-- Constants
threesixtyConstant = 6110
durationInSeconds = 1.4904  -- Set the desired duration in seconds

-- Function to perform the mouse movement for a set duration
function moveForDuration(duration)
    local startTime = GetRunningTime()
    local endTime = startTime + (duration * 1000)  -- Convert seconds to milliseconds
    
    while GetRunningTime() < endTime do
        MoveMouseRelative(threesixtyConstant, 0)
        Sleep(1)  -- Adjust the sleep time as needed
    end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

    -- Call the function when MB4 is pressed
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        moveForDuration(durationInSeconds)
    end
end
```

This is to make trick shots for Call of Duty work with mouse and keyboard, but it does not work if I move my mouse during the effect.

Any one have any ideas?

I tried to set DPI to zero, but that did not work.

Comment: GHub is unable to prevent user from moving the mouse.